# Get list of AppWidgetProviders in my app's package

Tags: android, android-appwidget, android-package-managers, appwidgetprovider

Is there an easy way to get a list of `AppWidgetProviders` that are in my app's package? I want to iterate over them and inspect some data from their corresponding `AppWidgetProviderInfo` objects at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Call `getInstalledProviders()` on the `AppWidgetManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetManager.html#getInstalledProviders%28%29), iterate over the list, and pay attention to those whose [`AppWidgetProviderInfo` `provider` `ComponentName`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProviderInfo.html#provider) is for your package.

Comment: Is there no way to get it just for my package? That list could be potentially large.

Comment: @Karakuri: "That list could be potentially large" -- not really. "Is there no way to get it just for my package?" -- since you want the `AppWidgetProviderInfo` objects, no.